# concatenate netcdf variables using indexes from a text file

Tags: shell-script, text

I have a bunch of netcdf files containing a variable vel_u of which I only want to extract certain values. I already determined the indexes of these values. They are stored in I.txt and J.txt
As you can see in the code below, I am concatenating using the function

```
ncrcat -C -F -d dimension1,from,to -d dimension2,from,to -v variable files_to_extract_from.nc file_to_write_to.nc
```

When I run my code below, I get the same error every loop run:

```
    ncrcat: ERROR parsing hyperslab specification for dimension nj_u,,
Must specify minimum and/or maximum value since stride is also empty
ncrcat: HINT Conform request to hyperslab documentation at http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#hyp
```

This makes me think that the part 'from,to' `${arrJ[i]},${arrJ[i+1]}` of my code is not working well. So it does not know the indexes. My indexes are stored in I.txt and J.txt. for example 181, 195, ... and every loop I want the next index to be used to extract from the files. So iteration 1

```
nj_u,181,182
```

iteration 2

```
nj_u,195,196
```

and so on.
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

outputNumber="$(ls -1q *_??????.nc | wc -l)" # what is the number of files in this directory
echo "the number of output netcdf files is ${outputNumber}"

valueI= `cat I.txt`
valueJ= `cat J.txt`
for ((i=1; i<=outputNumber; i++))
do
        arrI=($valueI)
        arrJ=($valueJ)

        ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,${arrJ[i]},${arrJ[i+1]} -d ni_u,${arrI[i]},${arrI[i+1]} -v vel_u *_??????.nc NewFile.nc
#every loop I should extract four numbers from every file

done
```

Another problem is that with this code it seems like NewFile.nc will be overwritten in every loop.

So two questions:

1. How do I make sure it reads in the right indexes?
2. How do I store the extracted values from every loop in the same .nc file without overwriting the old one?

Comment: You can't have whitespace after the `=` sign in the assignments of `valueI` and `valueJ`. In fact why not change the command substitutions to more modern `$(...)` form as well `valueI=$(cat I.txt)`

Comment: @steeldriver this took care of my first question, now I just need to find a way to append all those things together in a loop

Comment: I suggest adding an `echo` to your `ncrcat` command (or running the script with `set -x`) so that you can see exactly what's getting passed to the function. But I suspect this is now a question about netCDF rather than Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `I.txt` and `J.txt` will contain `outputNumber` values? The `arrI` will start at index `0` then and you'll need

```
for ((i=0; i<outputNumber; i++))
```

otherwise you'll end up with an index too high and have a missing parameter like the error message suggests.

Btw, why do you assign `arrI=($valueI)` in each loop? You can do it once before the loop.

Comment: this gave met the error `WARNING: Possible instance of Schweitzer data hole requiring better diagnostics TODO #148
HINT: If operation fails, try multislabbing (http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#msa) wrapped dimension using ncks first, and then apply ncrcat to the resulting file
` with the comment of @steeldriver it seems to read the indexes just fine